# CakePhp belongsTo relation issue

Tags: cakephp

I have 2 models Profiles and Messages. When i try to get all messages in its controller, cake doesn`t return any profiles in result array.
In Message controller:

```
$this->Message->recursive=3;
$m=$this->Message->find('all');
```

Models:

```
class Message extends AppModel {    
var $name = 'Message';
var $primaryKey = 'id';
var $useTable = 'messages';
var $belongsTo = array(
  'Profile' => array(
   'className' => 'Profile',
   'foreignKey' => 'author_id',
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
       'order' => ''
  ));
```

And

```
 class Profile extends AppModel {   
    var $name = 'Profile';
    var $primaryKey = 'id';
    var $useTable = 'profiles';
    var $belongsTo = array(
  'Account' => array(
   'className' => 'Account',
   'foreignKey' => 'account_id',
   'conditions' => '',
   'fields' => '',
   'order' => ''
  ));
  var $hasMany = array(
      'Message' => array(
           'className' => 'Message',
           'foreignKey' => 'Author_id',
           'dependent' => false,
           'conditions' => '',
           'fields' => '',
           'order' => '',
           'limit' => '',
           'offset' => '',
           'exclusive' => '',
           'finderQuery' => '',
           'counterQuery' => ''
      ));
```

P.S. I cant wait 7 hours for answer option.
I found solution eventually, my Message model filename was messageS.php, as soon as i renamed it to message.php, got everything i needed. I it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Per your answer, (but also relevant to other people), if you're pretty sure your associations are correct, the next step is to check your filenames to make sure they [fit the conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html?highlight=convention) (singular model).

Another note, if you're using recursive 3, (wasn't aware it went higher than 2, but apparently it does), you're probably better off using CakePHP's [Containable Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html?highlight=containable#ContainableBehavior).  Even using recursive of 2 is usually excessive.

Answer (score 0):

**write in Message.php model file:**

var $belongsTo = array(

'Profile' => array(

```
'className' => 'Profile',

'foreignKey' => 'author_id',

'conditions' => '',

'fields' => '',

'order' => ''
```

));

---

**write in Profile.php model file:**

var $hasMany = array(

'Message' => array(

```
   'className' => 'Message',

   'foreignKey' => 'Author_id',  // Hear you "Author_id" should change as "author_id"

   'dependent' => false,

   'conditions' => '',

   'fields' => '',

   'order' => '',

   'limit' => '',

   'offset' => '',

   'exclusive' => '',

   'finderQuery' => '',

   'counterQuery' => ''
```

));

---

**Controller:**

$m=$this->Message->find('all');

Now its working fine...Enjoy..